# Telethon get message buttons with python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Is there a way to get the URL or/and text of a button below the message?

I'm using telethon with python.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the buttons of a message using its `message.buttons` property.
This property returns a list, each element of list is a row(list) of [MessageButton](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html?highlight=MessageButton#module-telethon.tl.custom.messagebutton).

For example, if you want to access the URL or text of send music to friends button which is in row 1 and column 0 (**0 based index**), you can use the following code:

```py
peer_username = "Telegram identifier"
message = client.get_messages(peer_username)[0]

message_button = message.buttons[1][0]

text = message_button.text
url = message_button.url
```

Sometimes the `url` property in the MessageButton is empty, and you can use its `button` property to access the [KeyboardButton](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/keyboard_button.html). For example:

```py
url = message_button.button.url
```